# Python booleanos y listas

Tags: python, lista, booleano

esto es algo pequeño en lo que decidí meterme, pero estoy estancado. Se supone que este mini programa pasa la edad de un perro en años humanos a años perro. Ya tengo la parte que calcula la edad, ahora quiero que de un comentario de acuerdo a la edad del perro, por ejemplo, si el perro tiene menos de año y medio, devuelva cachorro; pero no se como hacer la línea. Por ahora estoy probando asignar rangos para cada uno. Apenas estoy empezando con este lenguaje y aún no se tratar con listas y booleanos

```
dog_age_years =input("¿cuantos años humanos completos tiene su perro?:")
dog_age_months = input ("¿y cuantos meses?:")

years = (int(dog_age_years)*7)
months =((int(dog_age_months)/12)*7)
años_perrunos = (years + months)

print("la edad de su perro es:"+años_perrunos)
```

Esta es la parte con la que tengo el problema:

```
print( cachorro=(0,11) ,adulto=(11,35),longevo=(35,140))
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios problemas evidentes en tu código.

No deberías usar caracteres especiales ni acentos, por lo que la ñ no se debería usar

La variable `años_perrunos` al hacer el `print("la edad de su perro es:"+años_perrunos)` es una variable de tipo numerica (probablemente float) y no puedes concatenar un número con un string sin castear usando str(var)

Y por último no puedes pasarle argumentos con keys a un print, para definir en que categoría/clasificación/etapa se encuentra el perro debes usar simples IF y ELIF lo que quedaría así:

```
dog_age_years =input("¿cuantos años humanos completos tiene su perro?:")
dog_age_months = input ("¿y cuantos meses?:")

years = (int(dog_age_years)*7)
months =((int(dog_age_months)/12)*7)
anios_perrunos = (years + months)

print("la edad de su perro es:"+str(anios_perrunos))
if anios_perrunos <11:
    pritn("Cachorro")
elif anios_perrunos <35:
    print("Adulto")
elif anios_perrunos < 140:
    print("Longevo")
```

Espero sea útil.

Comment: Estas diciendo que la última línea de mi código da problema por la ñ?. Por cierto gracias por responder

Comment: Creo que funciona sin embargo es poco recomendable usar esa sintaxis

Comment: El problema es que debes usar la misma identacion para todo el código, revisa que todo esté con 4 espacios o todo este con 1 tab.. no se puede mezclar.

Answer (score 0):

te dejo como lo habría resuelto yo para ademas tenga verificación de datos (No puedes tener mas de 12 meses ni menos de 0. Espero te ayude, un saludo

```
if __name__=="__main__":   
    print (">>> Conversor de años perro a años humano <<<")
    anios_perro= int(input("Ingrese cuantos años humanos tiene su perro: "))
    meses_perro= int(input("Ingrese cuantos meses: "))
    
    if anios_perro >= 0:
        if meses_perro <= 12 and meses_perro >= 0:
            edad= float((anios_perro)*7 + ((meses_perro)*7/12))
            print (f"Edad de su perro: {edad}")
            
            if edad < 11:
                print ("Es cachorro")
            elif edad < 35:
                print ("Es Adulto")
            elif edad < 140:
                print ("Es Longevo")
        else:
            print ("Cantidad de meses incorrecta")
    else:
        ("Cantidad de años incorrecta")
```

Comment: Primero: A que te refieres con que no puede tener más de doce meses?

Answer (score 0):

La única parte de tu código que tiene problemas es

```
print("la edad de su perro es:"+años_perrunos)
```

No se puede concatenar string con enteros, float, booleanos, etc. Debes hacer una conversión previa a str:

```
print("la edad de su perro es:" + str(años_perrunos))
```

Si quisieras trabajar los rangos de edad con [estructuras de datos](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) tipo listas, tuplas, etc... te aconsejo, en este caso, el uso de diccionarios. Obviamente hay que recorrer el diccionario con un ciclo para poder comparar con cada valor.

```
rango = {'cachorro':(0, 11), 'adulto':(11, 35), 'longevo':(35, 140)}
rango_edad = '<Fuera de rango>'
for nombre, valor in rango.items():
    if valor[0] <= años_perrunos <= valor[1]:
        rango_edad = nombre
        break

print(f"El rango de edad es {rango_edad}")
```

La variable `rango_edad` tiene el valor inicial de `<fuera de rango>`, pero al entrar al `for` y cumplirse cualquier condición, se sobreescribe con el rango correspondiente y se rompe el ciclo con `break` para salir de él. Si no se cumple ninguna condición (edad > 140, o edad < 0) entonces se queda con el valor incial.
El print hace uso de [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (Python 3.7+)

Comment: También pensé en usarlo así pero no quiero que comente solo con un numero sino con un rango por ejemplo que diga cachorro si la edad del perro (en años perrunos) es menor a 10  en ese caso podría montar un rango en vez de un número?

Comment: De hecho @PabloM , de la forma como lo describes, es como se debería indexar el diccionario correctamente. Inicialmente lo puse al revés para que lo entendieras mejor. Ya modifiqué el código como lo requerías.

Comment: Gracias  me diste buenas ideas para aplicar